# Java Get CPU Utilization Rate

Tags: java, cpu-load

Does anyone know how to get CPU Utilization Rate in Java 17?
I'm trying:

```
import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(
                OperatingSystemMXBean.class);

        System.out.println(osBean.getCpuLoad());
     }
}
```

I realized that CPU utilization should not be confused with CPU load.
So I believed that my function getCpuLoad is not what I expected.
So my question is: What is the function to get CPU Utilization Rate?

Comment: You imported the wrong class.  Use [java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html).  Never import a class starting with “sun.” or “com.sun.”.

Comment: @VGR I tried with your import solution but the function getCpuLoad() got wrong\

Comment: Apparently you can cast the returned MXBean to com.sun.management.OperatingSystem.MXBean, according to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html).

Comment: @VGR I just realized that CPU utilization should not be confused with CPU load. So I believe that my function getCpuLoad is not what I expected. Do you have any idea to get CPU Utilization Rate?